# can't add a new machine data source

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

I am trying to connect microsoft Access 2016 to my database in MSSQL 2012. However, i can't seem to be able to add a new machine data source. I can complete the connection test without any problems http://puu.sh/oUViC/d97cb71720.png. But afterwards it doesn's show up in my list of available machine data sources. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Note, that there is 32 and 64 bit version of ODBC `c:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe` and `c:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` as I know in windows 10 all connections are shown in both consoles but for example in win7 there are 2 different consoles and if you add connection in 64bit console you will not see it in 32bit console.

Comment: I tried to add the data source by using the administrator in c:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe and now it works! thanks!